# Finding x in a single-variate equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve this? $k$ is given, an it's a constant $0 \leq k \leq 1$.

$$(x-1)*0.8*(1-x)^{k}+0.2*x^{k+1}=0$$

What kind of equation is this? I'm not even sure what solver should I google for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the problem more general :
 you are looking for the solution of $$-a(1-x)^{k+1}+(1-a)x^{k+1}=0$$ that is to say $$a(1-x)^{k+1}=(1-a)x^{k+1}$$ Assuming $x\neq 0$, divide each side by $x^{k+1}$ to get $$a \frac {(1-x)^{k+1}}{x^{k+1}}=1-a\implies a\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)^{k+1}=1-a$$ Define $y=\frac {(1-x)}{x}$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: that first step to make the problem more general was brilliant

Comment: Thank you ! I always prefer to make the problem more general. But you can solve $-a(1-x)^{k+1}+bx^{k+1}=0$ in the same manner (provided that asolution exists).

Comment: I meant negating $(x-1)$ to add it to the exponent. Wouldn't have thought of that